# Can I pass a parameter from a layout XML to a method in the MainActivity?

Tags: java, android, xml, methods, parameter-passing

I'm sorry if this is a noob question but I'm new to XML and Android as a whole.

I am making a basic calculator in Android, and basically I want to write a method to handle all of the numerical button presses. I want to pass in a parameter into the method from the XML like so..

```
 <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/button_8"
        android:textSize="40dp"
        android:onClick="num_pressed(8)" 
 />
```

and have that method in the main activity do whatever with that number (I haven't decided what exactly to do with it yet, but that isn't part of my question).

So to clarify, in my app I have buttons for numbers 0-9, symbols "+", "-", "*", "/", "." and "C". Instead of writing a separate method for each number I thought it would be more efficient to have all of the numbers use the same method, and simply pass in a variable so it works for them all in the same way.

Can I do this or do I have to go about it completely differently?

Comment: So what do you want? Use one method for all buttons?

Comment: Yeah, sorry if I didn't make it clear. I want to have a common method for buttons 0-9, and the other buttons will probably have thier own methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow the below code for getting button events.

```
public void num_pressed(View view) {

        switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.button1:
            //perform operation
            break;

        case R.id.button2:
            //perform operation
            break;
        case R.id.button3:
            //perform operation
            break;
        case R.id.button4:
            //perform operation
            break;
        case R.id.button5:
            //perform operation
            break;
        case R.id.button6:
            //perform operation
            break;
        case R.id.button7:
            //perform operation
            break;
        case R.id.button8:
            //perform operation
            break;
        case R.id.button9:
            //perform operation
            break;
            case R.id.buttonplus:
                //perform operation
                break;
        default:
            break;
        }

        }
```

Comment: Ah yes, I remember doing so code similar to this in college, this could help! Thanks.

Comment: I ended up using a method similar to this, thank you very much for the reply!

Answer (score 0):

No you can't do pass a parameter to method, but you can set tag for a view and check it in your code.
The simple way to achieve this to set tag for your Button:

```
 <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/button_8"
        android:textSize="40dp"
        android:onClick="num_pressed"
        android:tag="8"
 />
```

And in your code, you can do like this:

```
public void num_pressed(View view) {
  String a = (String) view.getTag(); // here will be 8 for button.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot pass a parameter from XML but you can do this,

You have in strings.xml : 8
You have in layout.xml :

```
<Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/button_8"
        android:textSize="40dp"
        android:onClick="num_pressed" 
 />
```

In activity do this for numbers :

```
public void num_pressed(View view) {
    int number = Integer.parseInt(((Button) view).getText().toString());
}
```

Edit: Similarly for symbols just skip parsing as Integer, and I would suggest have two different methods for numbers and symbols because (as you told) in Calculator the working for these keys will differ alot.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I think I would end up parsing the variables at some point so this should help a lot.

Comment: @bansal21ankit It's not good idea to parse text on button. All views have "tag" exactly for cases like this.

Comment: @Demand I don't think there is some problem in parsing the text, and moreover why to attach another attribute or all-together a new string.

Comment: @bansal21ankit it's bad because it has different logic. I think it's bad to link your login to your represantion. For example tomorrow you will need to add icon to your button instead of text and your solution will not work anymore. I think, you must use tools which not links your representation to logic.

Comment: @Demand thanks for pointing, but arguing is waste now.. he just chose the worst answer among all as the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

You can call a method when the button is clicked. Also, you can assign tags to views(Buttons in your case) in xml. *(Tags are basically a way for views to have memories.)*

To be clear, use `android:onClick="MethodName"` to set which method to call. And use `android:tag="tagValue"` to assign tag to each view. The tag can be retrieved using `view.getTag()` from the method.

**Example Code:**
***xml:***

```
<Button
    ...Other Parameters...
    android:id="@+id/Button2"
    android:tag="2"
    android:onClick="method1"/>
<Button
    ...Other Parameters...
    android:id="@+id/Button3"
    android:tag="3"
    android:onClick="method1"/>
```

***Java:***

```
public void method1(View v){
    String tagValue = (String) v.getTag();
    if(tagValue.equals("2")){
        // add relevant code here
    }
    else if(tagValue.equals("3")){
        // add relevant code here
    }
    //complete the ramaining code
}
```